# How to trigger Google Adwords Conversion inside function with the conversion label passed to the function

Tags: ajax, google-ads-api

I looked around and didn't see any recent posts about this.  Most were much older (3-6 years)

For context, I am the dev and a SEO firm shared conversion snippets for a bunch of forms that are all ajax.  So I have to tigger the conversion on click and pass in the conversion label to the function instead of having different snippets on different pages.

Right now I am calling my function like so:

```
triggerConversion([MYCONVERSIONID], [UNIQUECONVERSIONLABEL]);
```

then I have a function:

```
function triggerConversion(conversionID, conversionLabel){
    console.log(conversionLabel);
    goog_snippet_vars = function() {
        var w = window;
        w.google_conversion_id = conversionID;
        w.google_conversion_label = conversionLabel;
        w.google_remarketing_only = false;
    }
    // DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE BELOW.
    goog_report_conversion = function(url) {
        goog_snippet_vars();    
        window.google_conversion_format = "3";
        var opt = new Object();
        opt.onload_callback = function() {
            if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
                window.location = url;
            }
        }
        var conv_handler = window['google_trackConversion'];
        if (typeof(conv_handler) == 'function') {
            conv_handler(opt);
        }
    }
}
```

This is not working as planned.  The to parameters are working correctly, but the conversion is not triggered.

There seem to be two problems:

1. Using Google Tag Assistant (a Google provided chrome extension), it appears that this function is triggered on load (which it shouldn't be).  The Tag Assistant is showing an error on page load that the id is malformed and the label is missing.  Both are just function parameters so of course its malformed on load.
2. This should only be triggered by calling the function.  This should only happen programmatically, in this case upon successful ajax call.

Not sure how to proceed.  But at the end of the day I only want to submit this conversion when the ajax returns successfully not on load.  I also need to pass the id and label to the function successfully.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if you're trying to use the async version of the Google Adwords conversion script. First of all, make sure that you're loading the right script (ideally in the `head` of your document):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Second, you don't need to set the conversion variables on the window object. When using the async script, you can just call `google_trackConversion` with the appropriate parameters directly. So your function could look something like this:

```
function triggerConversion(conversionID, conversionLabel){
    console.log(conversionLabel);
    var conv_handler = window['google_trackConversion'];
    if (typeof(conv_handler) == 'function') {
        conv_handler({
            google_conversion_id: conversionID,
            google_conversion_label: conversionLabel,
            google_remarketing_only: false
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll give that a try. if it works I'll give you the 50.